# Find modulus of two complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let z1 and z2 are two complex numbers such that $|z_1|=a$ and $|z_2|=b$ satisfying the equation $3z_1 ^2 -2z_1 z_2 +2z_2 ^2 =0$ and also Re$(\frac{z_1-2}{z_1 + 2})=0$ . We have to find value of a and b .

My try

let z1 = x +iy

putting this value in Re$(\frac{z_1-2}{z_1 + 2})=0$ .

I got $a^2 =4 $ .

but now how to proceed .

Comment: Maybe this info can Help: $$z_1=\frac{z_2(1+i\sqrt{5})}{3} \text { and } \frac{z_2(1-i\sqrt{5})}{3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z_1=p+iq\implies a^2=p^2+q^2$

$$\dfrac{z_1-2}{z_1+2}=\dfrac{\{(p-2)+iq\}\{(p+2)-iq\}}{(p+2)^2+q^2}$$

$$\implies0=(p^2-4)+q^2\implies a^2=4$$

$$\dfrac{z_1}{z_2}=\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{4-24}}6=\dfrac{2\pm\sqrt5i}3$$

Taking modulus $$\dfrac ab=\dfrac{\sqrt{2^2+5}}3=?$$